# C++ : Loop Array

Tags: c++

Been stuck at this for the past hour. I have tried figuring out the problem with this piece of code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if(chosenSeat = seatz[5][7]) {
            
            cout << "Sorry, that seat is already taken. Please choose another." << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, the 'cout' kept looping multiple times when I only wanted to show it once. Somehow when I tried rearranging the order of the code to try and fix it, I managed to mess it up even more. Now the whole code block is showing its output! :(

What mistake have I made here? I've been stuck with this problem for the past two hours.

```
cout << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your seat number to reserve: ";
    cin >> chosenSeat;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if(chosenSeat = seatz[5][7]) {
                    
                    cout << "Sorry, that seat is already taken. Please choose another." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (chosenSeat == seatNum [i][j]) {
                    seatz [i][j] = seatNum [i][j];
                    seatNum [i][j] = 0;
                cout << "Your seat has successfully been reserved." << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(chosenSeat == 0 || chosenSeat > 35)
        cout << "Invalid seat number.";
        while (cin.fail()){
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits <streamsize> :: max(), '\n');
            cout << "Invalid seat number.";
        }
```

Comment: Do you meant `seatz[i][j]` instead of `seatz[5][7]`? Otherwise the loops are unnecessary

Comment: `=` != `==`; the first is assignment, the latter comparison.

Comment: Also, did you mean `if (chosenSeat == seatz[...])` (`==` for comparison, `=` for assignment)

Comment: `chosenSeat == seatz[i][j]` instead of `chosenSeat = seatz[5][7]`? (improve your warning level to catch issue with `=` instead of `==`).

Comment: int seatNum [5][7] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21},
 {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28}, {29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35},};
 int chosenSeat, i, j, y;
 int seatz[5][7];

@kuro 

prior to the codes shown above, i have declared the following values.

Comment: @JerichoUbana, so, why are you checking `seatz[5][7]` in loop? That makes no sense and it also try to access element outside array limit. Also by your code, `seatz` is not assigned

Comment: I would recommend `bool seats[35] = {};` and then check if `seats[chosenSeat]` is set or not. Keep it simple.

Comment: Also, check for a valid seat number *before* you try to reserve it.

Answer (score 0):

### **Solution(s):**

I understand what you're attempting to do, and considering there's little repeatable code ( considering what's posted is broken ), I'll offer some advice / alternative methods.

1. In your matrix check, you're using a incorrect operand of `=` opposed to `==`.
2. When checking for valid seats, try creating a class dedicated to storing variables for the seats.

**Example:**

```
class CSeats
{
    public:  
    int m_iSeatIndex; // An example of where you can store / save seat data.
};
```

There's a multitude of ways you could fix the code, but what's provided is too minimal and offers low insight toward the core issue.